# MultiValueDictKeyError when custom ID field is missing

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I get a MultiValueDictKeyError in Django 1.6 when I define a fieldset or field in my NestedStackedInline. There I have a custom ID as CharField and wanted to hide that field. But when I do that by exclude=('id',), defining fields without that or just making it readonly, I get a MultiValueDictKeyError.

Here my code:

```
class MaterialInline(NestedStackedInline):
    fieldsets = ('name', 'amount', 'date') 
    #without custom id I get that error(id=models.Charfield(primary_key=True))
    model = Material
    extra = 1
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(Material)

class ResearchAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MaterialInline, ]
    fields =('id','subject', 'topic')
```

Error:

```
 Exception Type:    MultiValueDictKeyError
 Exception Value:   "u'material_set-0-id'"
 Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 301
...
/home/administrator/src/django-nested-inlines/nested_inlines/admin.py in change_view

269. self.add_nested_inline_formsets(request, inline, formset)

/home/administrator/src/django-nested-inlines/nested_inlines/admin.py in add_nested_inline_formsets

65. for form in formset.forms:
```

Does anyone knows that problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide more information like code, error, traceback

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Turned out that I just needed to make the field not editable in the model. Note the last argument here:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=128, editable=False)
```

Comment: This caught me badly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a HiddenInput widget on the id field.  So, define a model form for the admin:

```
class MaterialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=HiddenInput, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Material
```

Then replace

```
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(Material)
```

in `MaterialInline` with

```
    form = MaterialForm
```

Clearly a bit more work would be required to get it working with the autocomplete.